# 2 клика по элементу

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не могу сделать 2 клика по элементу. У меня есть коллекция div блоков, на них повешен скрипт выделения активного блока. В чем суть: чтобы произошло какое то действие у активного блока, надо щелкнуть на него один раз, на не активный - 2 раза(1 раз - для того чтобы его выделить и сделать его активным, 2 раз - для того чтобы выполнить какое либо действие). Проблема в том что когда нажимаешь один элемент на другой и потом щелкаешь элемент на который вы уже нажали он выделяется и одновременно выполняет определенное действие(грубо говоря клик сохраняется, а этого мне не нужно)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_1.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="block">  
            1      
        </div>
        <div class="block">    
            2    
        </div>
        <div class="block">  
            3      
        </div>
        <div class="block"> 
            4       
        </div>
        <div class="block"> 
            5       
        </div>
        <div class="block">  
            6      
        </div>
        <div class="block"> 
            7       
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="js.js"></script>
</html>
body
{
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
}
.content
{
   
    width: 30vw;
    height: 30vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
   
}

.block
{
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    height: 5vw;
    background-color: brown;
    margin: 0 0 1vw;
}

.content .active{
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #5dcc41 0%, #31d86f 100%);
    color: #ffffff;
  }
/**
 * @param {number} value 
 * @param {number} min 
 * @param {number} max 
 */
function minMax(value, min, max) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max)
}

/**
 * @param {HTMLElement} container 
 * @param {string} queryItem 
 */
function listItems(container, queryItem) {
  const items = [...container.querySelectorAll(queryItem)]
  const { length } = items
  const activeClass = 'active'
  const state = { selected: 0 }

  function update() {
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      let g = 0;
      if (i == state.selected)
      {
        items[i].classList.add(activeClass);
        items[i].addEventListener("click", elemEventHandler);
        
      }
      else
        items[i].classList.remove(activeClass)  
       
    }   
  }
  var elemEventHandler = function() 
  {
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
      if(items[i].classList.contains("active"))   
      {
        
        alert("ggп")
        
      } 
      else
      {
        
        items[i].removeEventListener("click", elemEventHandler);
        
      }
    }
  }
  const fix = () => {
    if (state.selected >= length) state.selected = length - 1
    if (state.selected < 0) state.selected = 0
  }

  const incState = () => {
    state.selected++
    fix()
    update()
  }

  const decState = () => {
    state.selected--
    fix()
    update()
  }

  /**
   * @param {KeyboardEvent} param0 
   */
  const keyDown = ({ key }) => {
    if (key === 'ArrowUp') decState()
    if (key === 'ArrowDown') incState()
  }

  addEventListener('keydown', keyDown)

  /**
   * @param {number} index 
   */
  function select(index) {
    state.selected = minMax(index, 0, length - 1)
    update()
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    items[i].onclick = select.bind(null, i)
  }

  update()

  return () => {
    removeEventListener('keydown', keyDown)

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      items[i].onclick = null
      delete items[i].onclick
    }
  }
}
listItems(document.querySelector('.content'), '.block')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы назначаете слушатель "второго" нажатия на каждый когда-либо нажатый элемент в функции `update`, хотя уже есть слушатель нажатий: `items[i].onclick = select.bind(null, i)`.

Решение: не добавлять новых обработчиков нажатий, изменить прежнюю функцию.
Теперь она выглядит следующим образом:

```
items[i].onclick = function() {
    if (i == state.selected) alert("ggп");
    else select(i);
}
```

```js
/**
 * @param {number} value 
 * @param {number} min 
 * @param {number} max 
 */
function minMax(value, min, max) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max)
}

/**
 * @param {HTMLElement} container 
 * @param {string} queryItem 
 */
function listItems(container, queryItem) {
  const items = [...container.querySelectorAll(queryItem)]
  const content = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
  const {
    length
  } = items
  const activeClass = 'active'
  const state = {
    selected: 0,
    lastSelected: 0
  }

  function update() {
    items[state.lastSelected].classList.remove(activeClass);
    items[state.selected].classList.add(activeClass);
  }
  const fix = () => {
    if (state.selected >= length) state.selected = length - 1;
    if (state.selected < 0) state.selected = 0;
  }

  const incState = () => {
    state.lastSelected = state.selected++;
    fix();
    update();
  }

  const decState = () => {
    state.lastSelected = state.selected--;
    fix();
    update();
  }

  /**
   * @param {KeyboardEvent} param0 
   */
  const keyDown = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let key = event.key;
    if (key === 'ArrowUp') decState();
    if (key === 'ArrowDown') incState();
    let contentParams = content.getBoundingClientRect();
    let itemParams = items[state.selected].getBoundingClientRect();
    if (contentParams.top > itemParams.top) content.scrollBy({left:0, top:itemParams.top-contentParams.top, behavior: "smooth"});
    if (contentParams.bottom < itemParams.bottom) content.scrollBy({left:0, top:itemParams.bottom-contentParams.bottom, behavior: "smooth"});
  }

  addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);

  /**
   * @param {number} index 
   */
  function select(index) {
    state.lastSelected = state.selected;
    state.selected = index;
    update();
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    items[i].onclick = function() {
        if (i == state.selected) alert("ggп");
        else select(i);
    }
  }

  update();

  return () => {
    removeEventListener('keydown', keyDown);

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      items[i].onclick = null;
      delete items[i].onclick;
    }
  }
}
listItems(document.querySelector('.content'), '.block')
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  height: 5vw;
  background-color: brown;
  margin: 0 0 1vw;
}

.content .active {
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #5dcc41 0%, #31d86f 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_1.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="block">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      6
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      7
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="js.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо вам большое.

Comment: Кстати, возможно это не по теме, но можно как то сделать чтобы работал скролл .content если листаешь блоки стрелочками на клавиатуре?

Comment: @vovaVS я добавил пролистывание за выделенным элементом (см. `keyDown`)

Comment: Двойная благодарность.

Answer (score 0):

Просто проверяйте при нажатии - есть ли класс 'active'.
Если есть, производите действие.

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
let content = document.querySelector('.content');

content.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{  
  if (e.target.classList.contains('active')) {    
    alert('Second click');
    return;
  }  
  if (e.target.classList.contains('block')) {    
    items.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('active'));
    e.target.classList.add('active');
  }  
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  height: 5vw;
  background-color: brown;
  margin: 0 0 1vw;
}

.content .active {
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #5dcc41 0%, #31d86f 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_1.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="block active">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      6
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      7
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="js.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. То что нужно. Да хранит вас бог.

Comment: Только есть одна правка, можете сделать чтобы 1 элемент был сразу активным

Comment: @vovaVS  в HTML просто допишите класс active в нужный вам блок, который должен быть активным с самого начала

Comment: Уже все сделал. Благодарю за ответ